# Can't get user input in to password_verify()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

here is the login code, I'm trying to get password verify to work but It doesn't want to. It seems like this `count($sql->fetchAll()) > 0` is the problem or that I am calling the wrong variable to the `password_verify()`.

```
    $signup = isset($_POST['signup'] ) ? $_POST['signup'] : false;
$submit = isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ? $_POST['submit'] : false;
$username = isset( $_POST['username'] ) ? $_POST['username'] : false;
$password = isset( $_POST['password'] ) ? $_POST['password'] : false;

if( $submit && $username && $password ) {

  $sql = $DB_con->prepare( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=:user_name AND user_pass=:user_pass" );
  $sql->bindParam( ':user_name', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $sql->bindParam( ':user_pass', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $check_user=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $success = $sql->execute();
  $verify = password_verify($password, check_user['user_pass']);
    // Successfully logged in!
  if($success && count($sql->fetchAll()) > 0 && $verify) {

    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;  
    // Unset errors
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
  }
  else {
    // display an error
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'That user doesn\'t exist'; 
  }
}
else {
  //displays error
  $_SESSION['error'] = 'Please enter all fields';
}
if($signup) {
  header('Location: signup.php');
}
exit;
```

Here is the signup code

```
function register($uname,$umail,$upass)
    {

        $DB_con = null;

try
{
     $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", "$username" ,"$password");
     $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
     echo $e->getMessage();
}   



       try
       {
           $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

           $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass) 
                                                       VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass)");

           $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
           $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
           $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);            
           $stmt->execute(); 
           return $stmt; 

       }
       catch(PDOException $e)
       {
           echo $e->getMessage();
       }    

    }
```

Comment: Two things I could see: missing `$` in `check_user` in your verify, and you're fetching before you execute.

Comment: And syntax error in the register function, see the highlighting

Comment: Oh, another: you're trying to select where the password match the unhashed one, you can't do that when using `password_hash()`. Remove the password from your where clause

Comment: @Qirel, Hi mate thank you very much for your reply, the syntax error in the register function was just me being hasty to change login info to post it. When you say fetching before you execute do you mean I need to put $check_user=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); after the $success?

Comment: Yes, basically. There are other issues too, I've posted an answer with the issues I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that needs to be cleaned up with this piece of code.

Let's start with your `register()` function. There's a clear syntax-error here (where you make the connection), the `""$password"`. Then that function don't know what `$dbname`, `$username` or `$password` are (for the connection), these variables aren't in the *scope* of the function (it can see it). Usually it's better to pass the connection object as a parameter, not create a new object for each time you call the `register()` function. Modified for that and cleaned a bit, it would look like this

```
function register($DB_con, $uname ,$umail, $upass) {
    try {
        $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_email, user_pass) 
                                                   VALUES (:uname, :umail, :upass)");

        $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
        $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);            
        return $stmt->execute(); 

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

and be used like

```
register($DB_con, 'Nader', 'example@example.com', 'pa$$w0rd'); // True or false
```

Then onto your sign-in. This is a little messy, and you're doing a few things wrong. What I've found so far is...

- Fetching *after* execution
- Selecting `WHERE` the unhashed password is equal to the hashed one (won't return any rows)
- `count($sql->fetchAll()) > 0` will be zero, because you already fetched once, and there will only be one user => this means one row. Fetching one means there are no more to fetch, so `fetchAll()` is empty!
- You don't need to do any more checks than `if ($check_user=$sql->fetch())` to check if there are rows

Corrected and accounted for the points above, your code would look something like this

```
$signup = isset($_POST['signup']) ? $_POST['signup'] : false;
$submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : false;
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : false;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : false;

if ($submit && $username && $password) {
    $sql = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=:user_name");
    $sql->bindParam(':user_name', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->execute();

    if ($check_user=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        if (password_verify($password, $check_user['user_pass'])) {
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;  
            // Unset errors
            unset($_SESSION['error']);
        } else {
            // Invalid password
        }
    } else {
        // No user with that username
    }
} else {
    //displays error
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Please enter all fields';
}

if ($signup) {
    header('Location: signup.php');
}
exit;
```

*This assumes unique usernames in the DB*

There might be more issues which I can't see, which is why you should enable error-reporting by adding

```
<?php
error_reoprting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

at the top of your file (errors shouldn't be displayed like that in a live environment).

Comment: Hi, thank you so so much for your help it's working now. I'm really new to PHP so I  tried a lot of different things hence the messy code, thank you so much for taking the time to modify it. In regards to the DB connection I changed the actual values to $dbname etc etc since it had my uni credentials as the values. In hindsight I should have used a different way to represent the values and I'll remember that for next time.

Comment: Happy to help! We all start somewhere ;-) You're doing good on starting with PDO using parameterized queries and proper password-hashing, so way to go on that! *Thumbs up* If this answer provided you with a good solution, please be sure to upvote and [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)! *Cheers*! :-)